# Botium Scripting Memory - Variable value not picked up in the utterance

Tags: chatbot

I have been unsuccessful so far in getting the scripting memory to work and looking for help please.

**Utterance in my test excel sheet** - How can I get $app-music?
ScriptingMemory tab content:

[image]

Expectation is: Botium to send $app-music values in the utterances to the bot
Actual behaviour: Botium sending variable name ($app-music) as opposed to the values.

Please can someone help me in getting this to work? TIA.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spotted two problems. First of all, variable names with a "-" are not allowed - only characters and numbers - see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48922663/Scripting+Memory+Variables) - choose another variable name, *$appmusic* for example.

Furthermore, the Excel area scanned by Botium starts in the second row, according to your configuration, so you will have to move the scripting memory table one to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Florian.Fixed both and finally for it to work :)